# Castle Windsor Register components with base component

Tags: dependency-injection, castle-windsor

Hi I am trying to register 3 components with the base component as the parameter to them.

SomeBase is the base class for A and B. The Class ServiceImpl is the mail class which need to work on A and B which should be intiated with base class.

```
Class SomeBase
{
   Object objBase;
}
Class A : SomeBase
{
   A(SomeBase somebase)   
}
Class B : SomeBase
{
   B(SomeBase somebase)   
}

Class ServiceImpl
{
   service(SomeBase[] somebaseArray)
}

Registering the components - 

container.register(SomeBase)
container.register(A)
container.register(B)

var baseObj = resolve(SomeBase)
container.register(using factory = new A(baseObj))
container.register(using factory = new B(baseObj))

But this is not working the way it should.. 

Any help on this please?
```

Comment: I can't imagine that this will even compile. You say you have a base class but I don't see any class deriving from a base class. Please get your code as correct as possible.

Comment: Sorry for that, actually i just want to tell the scenario. this code is definately not compiled..